# Selecting rows with specified days in datetimeindex dataframe - Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetimeindex

I have a dataframe with datetimeindex. I only need those rows whose index belong to days specified in a list e.g. [1,2] for Monday and Tuesday. Can this be possible in pandas in a single line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC then the following should work:

```
df[df.index.to_series().dt.dayofweek.isin([0,1])]
```

Example:

```
In [9]:
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start=dt.datetime(2015,1,1), end = dt.datetime(2015,2,1)))
df[df.index.to_series().dt.dayofweek.isin([0,1])]

Out[9]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [2015-01-05 00:00:00, 2015-01-06 00:00:00, 2015-01-12 00:00:00, 2015-01-13 00:00:00, 2015-01-19 00:00:00, 2015-01-20 00:00:00, 2015-01-26 00:00:00, 2015-01-27 00:00:00]
```

So this converts the `DateTimeIndex` to a [`Series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_series.html) so that we can call [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin) to test for membership, using [`.dt.dayofweek`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.dayofweek.html) and passing `0,1` (this corresponds to Monday and Tuedsay), we use the boolean mask to mask the index

Another way is to construct a boolean mask without converting to a `Series`:

```
In [12]:
df[(df.index.dayofweek == 0) | (df.index.dayofweek == 1)]

Out[12]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [2015-01-05 00:00:00, 2015-01-06 00:00:00, 2015-01-12 00:00:00, 2015-01-13 00:00:00, 2015-01-19 00:00:00, 2015-01-20 00:00:00, 2015-01-26 00:00:00, 2015-01-27 00:00:00]
```

Or in fact this would work:

```
In [13]:
df[df.index.dayofweek < 2]

Out[13]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [2015-01-05 00:00:00, 2015-01-06 00:00:00, 2015-01-12 00:00:00, 2015-01-13 00:00:00, 2015-01-19 00:00:00, 2015-01-20 00:00:00, 2015-01-26 00:00:00, 2015-01-27 00:00:00]
```

**TIMINGS**

```
In [14]:
%timeit df[df.index.dayofweek < 2]
%timeit df[np.in1d(df.index.dayofweek, [1, 2])]

1000 loops, best of 3: 464 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 521 µs per loop
```

So my last method is slightly faster here than the np method

Comment: Thanks :). I wanted to do something like in your first example so that I can use the list I have, but Pandas 0.14 doesn't have .dt and I have a constraint on updating it at the moment. Any way we can do the same in 0.14?

Comment: The other methods should work though, otherwise something like: `df[df.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: x.dayofweek in([0,1]))]` will work but will be slow for large dfs as this is just a `for` loop

Comment: I ended up using df[np.in1d(df.index.dayofweek, [1, 2])], thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
In [3]: import pandas as pd
In [4]: import numpy as np

In [5]: index = pd.date_range('11/23/2015', end = '11/30/2015', freq='d')
In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(index),2),columns=list('AB'),index=index)

In [7]: df
Out[7]:
                   A         B
2015-11-23 -0.673626 -1.009921
2015-11-24 -1.288852 -0.338795
2015-11-25 -1.414042 -0.767050
2015-11-26  0.018223 -0.726230
2015-11-27 -1.288709 -1.144437
2015-11-28  0.121093  1.396825
2015-11-29 -0.791611 -1.014375
2015-11-30  1.223220 -1.223499


In [8]: df[np.in1d(df.index.dayofweek, [1, 2])]
Out[8]:
                   A         B
2015-11-24  0.116678 -0.715655
2015-11-25 -1.494921  0.218176
```

1 is actually Tuesday here. But that should be fairly easy to account for if needed.

The previous answer was posted while writing this, as a comparison:

```
In [15]: %timeit df.loc[df.index.to_series().dt.dayofweek.isin([0,1]).values]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.01 ms per loop

In [16]: %timeit df[np.in1d(df.index.dayofweek, [0, 1])]
1000 loops, best of 3: 393 µs per loop
```

Note this comparison was done on the test DF I created and I don't know how it necessarily extends to larger dataframes, though performance should be consistent.